# PNG is too sharp on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, web

Can anyone help me fix this?
The logo image on Google Chrome shows just fine, but on Internet Explorer it looks too sharp, I need a solution for this :C

Image of the bug:
[Png too sharp on IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRzWg.png)

Another image:
[Png too sharp on IE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSoFm.png)

This is how i display the image (in a div):

```
#topmenu-logo {
   background: url("/images/xCarga/logotipo.png") no-repeat center;
   background-color:#ececec;
   background-size: contain;
   width: 437px;
   height: 84px;
}
```

Comment: We can't diagnose an image...perhaps you would demo for us?

Comment: Added some more info

Comment: They seem to have different sizes

Comment: @HerrSerker added a better image check it out

Comment: We'd need the **actual** image being used in a demo.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Comment: The original image is really huge. The background-size: contain makes it shrink. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: I resized and saved as jpg, I realized it wasn't really a png problem it's the size, hadn't noticed the size of the actual image, thanks alot guys, how do I mark this as solved?

Comment: You click on the checkmark on my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a problem with the IE image rendering engine, which [is notoriously bad](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/e800cbaf-a539-43ba-b5f9-1d29fe709ddc/the-awful-internet-explorer-image-renderengine?forum=ieitprocurrentver).

You could try this IE interpolation mode:

```
img { -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor; }
```

EDIT: from your comment to the original question it looks like you are using a full-size version (3508x516 pixels!) of your logo on your homepage's header. You should really use a graphic program to resize the logo and use the smaller version (antialiased) on the homepage. Letting the browser resize such a big image causes performance problems. (Note: links removed.)

Comment: That worked, I resized it and saved it as a jpg too, thanks for this mate, If I could I would give you +rep but I'm not allowed yet lol, Could you just remove these links please I would like to not make them public, thanks @dr01

Comment: @Pablo You could accept the answer as correct by clicking the check mark and make it green

Comment: Done, links removed from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }
```